# How does Node.JS and/or Meteor get a callback from the database when a 3rd party software update the database

Tags: oracle, node.js, mongodb, meteor

I would like to use Meteor (Node.JS) to develop an application that will be used by 3,000+ concurrent users on a large size database.
I have looked at the nice examples and the idea to push changed data to the clients is very nice and very useful, but before I start the development I want to be sure how it works behind the scenes to be sure that when I have the application running with all these users it work fast with standard hardware.
I also require this to use Oracle as a database, but not sure that it is supported and if not, what are the requirements from an Oracle package to enable this facility.

I think that the server is having an active on going non-blocking query on the OPLOG table in mongodb and that is how we get the callback for all the changes in the database. Is that correct ? if so, is there a similar way to do it in Oracle ?

Thanks Roni.

Answer (score 2):

> I also require this to use Oracle as a database, but not sure that it is supported and if not, what are the requirements from an Oracle package to enable this facility.

Nope, meteor is currently mongo-only as they have implemented an in-browser library called minimongo. My guess is this project will never support oracle, but who knows. There is no mention of oracle support on the [meteor project roadmap](https://trello.com/board/meteor-roadmap/508721606e02bb9d570016ae)

Comment: Meteor now has a card for [Additional Database Support](https://trello.com/c/6ugalZMG/54-additional-database-support).

Answer (score 0):

Just happened to come across this question while searching at google.

However, if there are no native solutions. We can always figure out a way for a medium language to issue publishing.

Example Case:

Python will be used for synchronising data between Mongodb and Oracle (24/7 operation using cx_Oracle and MongoDB drivers from python)

Meteor Server will keep watch on what to publish
Meteor clients/browsers that subscribed to the channel that will be updated with oracle data.